# How to make checkbox ListTile with rounded box using Getx in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am relatively new to Flutter development and I want to implement checkbox as shown in the screenshot attached using GetX flutter. Also I want the borders of my check-boxes to be round.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGZzz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've mentioned in the screenshot.
You can achieve it with GetX as following:

Create a variable for keep tracking the checked value

```
final Rxn<int> selected = Rxn<int>();
```

Now you have to implement the UI with ***Obx*** widget to listen for the changes of observing variable '*selected*'

```html
Obx(
          () => Column(
            children: [
              CheckboxListTile(
                title: const Text('This is the title 1'),
                subtitle: const Text('This is the subtitle with ID 1'),
                checkColor: Colors.white,
                activeColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                checkboxShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                value: selected.value == 1,
                onChanged: (val) {
                  val ?? true ? selected.value = 1 : selected.value = null;
                },
              ),
              CheckboxListTile(
                title: const Text('This is the title 2'),
                subtitle: const Text('This is the subtitle with ID 2'),
                checkColor: Colors.white,
                activeColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                checkboxShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                value: selected.value == 2,
                onChanged: (val) {
                  val ?? true ? selected.value = 2 : selected.value = null;
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ))
```

The following will be the output:
[image: Screenshot of the output]

Answer (score 1):

You can make a CheckBox round by using the **shape** field and the **CircleBorder** class or **RoundedRectangleBorder** (if you want them to have rounded corners):

```
Checkbox(
      checkColor: Colors.white,
      value: isChecked,
      shape: CircleBorder(),
      onChanged: (bool? value) {
        setState(() {
          isChecked = value!;
        });
      },
    );
```

Result: [image]

Or:

```
Checkbox(
      checkColor: Colors.white,
      value: isChecked,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0))),
      onChanged: (bool? value) {
        setState(() {
          isChecked = value!;
        });
      },
    );
```

Result: [image]

To use GetX I think you should provide some code or example to explain what do you mean and what you want to exactly achieve, otherwise the best advice is probably to read the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/get/latest/) and check [some example](https://pub.dev/packages/get/example).